# SQL - Need to find a way to check whether a member has renewed

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

So, this is probably simple. I need to find a way to check whether a member of a scheme has renewed their membership or let it expire, I need to generate a simple list of those whom have not renewed.... There are complicating factors however, in that I cant use Excel, and it can only be a single step to Crystal reports (though I have solved the issue in Excel using a simple Countifs and if Formula)

Now for the problem.

The membership has specified Start/End Dates in separate columns in the table. It is easy to see whether this, in a row basis has expired. The issue is that if they have renewed, this is logged as a separate table entry linked by a Individual reference to the member. There are also multiple Qualifications I also need to test against.

So, whilst I can test the expiration date, the question is how can I test against the rest of the data, based on whether the Individual Reference and Qualification name and then check whether this is "Current". Doing this would enable me to therefore test whether the Membership has therefore been renewed, or not, on an individual line.

Any advice on methods would be appreciated.

Comment: sample data needed to understand the exact issue...

Comment: Not an option for me unfortunatly, which is frustating.

Comment: There is no dummy data? incase atleast database structure?

Comment: @Sparkind You don't have to provide real data, just an idea of what the table looks like (even if only the columns you care about) and what might be in them (call everyone 'John Smith123' if you have to). It's so we can provide an actual answer and not just a guess

Comment: Ah right, Sorry, new to this and havent worked with SQL for a while. Im going to test Johns Method first and Ill come back to it, but thanks for attempting to help all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what data you have and making assumptions out the wazoo, try something along these lines

```
select distinct Member_id, 
       case 
         when exists (select 1 
                      from members m2 
                      where m2.member_id = m1.member_id
                      and (m2.expiry_date is null
                           or m2.expiry_date > '2018-01-25'))
           then 'Active'
         else 'Expired'
       end as mem_status
from members m1
```

What the `exists` does is look and see if that member has an active status

Comment: JohnHC, Thanks for taking a look. essentially, I need to run a case, with the member number joined back to it.

Ill experiment with this method, as I think you have put me well on the right track.

Comment: John, Your answer got me about 90% of the way there. I hadn't realised you could use a case to do this. I had to change the number of columns to get it to work correctly, as there was an additional criteria which I needed to include.